# Calculate width required to fit text for a multiline UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel, word-wrap

I am trying to expand the width of a 2 line UILabel to accommodate a varying amount of text. To do this I am attempting to calculate the width required and then setting it to a width constraint I have set on the label.

However, everything I have done ignores the height/word wrapping, and returns the width required for a single line of text (not 2 lines). Any ideas on how i can find the width needed if 2 or more lines are used in the label?

I have tried using the following methods to find the width:

1.Using boundingRectWithSize to determine the appropriate size for a fixed height (height of 2 lines)

```
 CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, fixedHeight);
 NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: self.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle};

CGRect rect = [self.text boundingRectWithSize: maxSize
                                      options: (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin)
                                   attributes: attributes
                                      context: nil];
```

2. Using the sizeThatFits method to determine the appropriate size.

Thanks!

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `fixedHeight` you are passing is sufficient enough to accommodate multiple lines. To be safe you can use following

```
 CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX);   //where 300 is the width of label
```

Setting above height will make sure it takes into consideration multiple lines as width is limited. In previous case you were setting width to `MAXFLOAT` thus width was big enough to accommodate entire content in single line.

Comment: I just tried increasing the number height significantly, however it still calculates the width for a single line so I dont think that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be silly, but make sure that 'numberOfLines' property of the UILabel is set to 0, so that the size calculation methods can use multiline options.

Comment: I've tried both numberOfLines = 2 and numberOfLines = 0, but it doesn't appear to change the result.